# Getting error while starting the Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.2

Tags: websphere-8

I am getting following error in the console while starting my websphere application server 8.5.5.2 :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.tmPut(ILjava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry;)I
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1018)
    at sun.util.locale.LocaleObjectCache.get(LocaleObjectCache.java:81)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.getCandidateLocales(ResourceBundle.java:2330)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1310)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:732)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.(WSLauncher.java:115)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.processPropertiesFile(WSPreLauncher.java:580)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher$1.run(WSPreLauncher.java:303)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.setImplicitProperties(WSPreLauncher.java:300)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:146)

Comment: I have added WAS 8.5.5.2 in my Eclipse Neon and trying to start from Eclipse.

Comment: Can you start server from commandline using bin/startServer script?

Comment: I tried from the command line but getting same error

Comment: Try to run Eclipse with Java located in WebSphere\AppServer\java_xxx (depending on which SDK you have installed with your WAS).